# Removing shortcuts from ArcPad today

Tags: arcpad, shortcuts

I am using ArcPad 10.0.2.

I have created a shortcut that goes to ArcPad today menu, but now I want to remove it.

How do I do this?

Comment: Is this a question about working with the Windows operating system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this link regarding removing shortcuts:

[Remove Arcpad App shortcut 10.02](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/30149-Remove-Arcpad-App-shortcut-10.02)

Answer (score 3):

You either go to the SortCut Apps folder or to the project folder itself and simply delete the  lnk file. You can also delete the .ico if you like.

To add/remove other elements on the ArcPadtoday screen you can edit the XML file, in case you don't want the ArcPad default button on it.